# How to write a terminal emulator from scratch (or not from scratch)?

Tags: linux, terminal, d, terminal-emulator

As an exercise I'd like to write a terminal emulator for Linux from scratch in order to understand what moving parts are involved into it. My language of choice is D (because I'm learning it currently).

It obviously doesn't have to be something big. I'd like it to have a window with a background color (and opacity, later) displaying command promt. User may type in a command and it will spew out the result. Basic stuff. Except I'm not even sure where to start.

I suppose the visual part should be handled by something like gtk (which I never worked with), but what about everything else? Can someone please describe a possible architecture and what should I be looking at?

It would also be helpful to know which parts it makes sense to write from scratch (given my language of choice) and which parts I can use as third-party libraries or binaries.

I also realize there might exist other questions like this one, but I couldn't find quality answers. If you know such answers, please link to them.

Comment: why not "translate" your favorite open-source terminal from it's current language into `D`. You could then decide if you've learned enough, and you might find better terms (special case terminology) to do further research with. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think this question fits on stack overflow because its not very specific. I guess the best thing you can do is looking at other terminal emulators (which also might not be written in D) and port some code or look at them. But I don't think there is a general answer to what you should do because it is your project and you will decide what you will add and what you wont add. But if you want to look at a terminal emulator written in D, there is one on github: https://github.com/gnunn1/terminix

Comment: I suspect you may be conflating terminal emulators with shells. A terminal emulator just emulates a I/O device, it doesn't run commands or know anything about prompts. On Linux, a terminal emulator allocates a pseudo-terminal by opening the multiplexer device `/dev/ptmx` (maybe using `posix_openpt()`), this causes a slave device to appear at `/dev/pts`. Then, the terminal emulator typically spawns a shell with std{in,out,err} connected to the slave device.

Comment: Info on terminal emulators: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79334/how-does-a-linux-terminal-work http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con http://st.suckless.org/ ECMA-48, http://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html

Comment: A fantastic test of a terminal emulator is how well it handles the vim editor program. Granted it's a bit of a learning curve to learn vim if you don't know it, but with all of the refreshes, screen colors for syntax highlighting, and all, "vi" has a long history of breaking emulators.

Comment: GTK+ tutorial [Write your own terminal emulator](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-write-own-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

You already have an excellent terminal emulator implemented in D under Mozilla Public License. The code is here: https://github.com/gnunn1/terminix/tree/master/source/gx/terminix/terminal

A good start however would be Adam Ruppe's (author of "D Cookbook") https://github.com/adamdruppe/terminal-emulator .

Comment: Yeah, my terminal emulator is exactly what OP is asking for: it is 100% from scratch (well, I use xlib and the kernel but that doesn't count :) ) and handles a lot of common programs, including vim. It's actually quite a bit more complex than you'd think... terminal emulation is a pain in the butt. BTW: I actually use mine as my every day terminal, on both Windows (sshing back to my linux box like putty) and Linux. It is mildly buggy and inefficient in places, but no dealbreakers and besides, it is mine :P